# Is kabbah the center of the earth

Tags: geography, islam, mathematics, earth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about the Kabbah and the center of the earth](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6708/question-about-the-kabbah-and-the-center-of-the-earth)

In the following video it is claimed that Kabbah is the center of the earth. What is the scientific proof of this claim. Furthermore what is the proof behind the mathematical number 1.618 that appears in the video. Is it true that the frecuency of the appearance of this number can´t be deemed to coincidence?

Thanks for your answers. Please give enough scientifical references to your answers.

[Kabbah the center of the earth](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQJib4FL4qA)

Nota Bene: It is the Surface Center not the planetary center of the earth. That means that it into account the poles as being the most southwest and northern points.

Comment: Since the earth is a sphere, isn't it's center not on its surface?

Comment: The surface center. Not the planetary center. Thank's for the comment.

Comment: What's the geometric definition of the surface center of an arbitrary sphere?

Comment: This video just assumes that the Golden Ratio is somehow special, then tries to prove that Mecca lies on the "Golden Ratio" point of the earth's surface. The latitude may be correct, but there are two such latitudes which meet that requirement. The supposed proof that Mecca is on the golden longitude is ridiculous, in that it relies on a flattened projection of the earth whose end longitude and latitude are arbitrary and based on European dominance at the time that the standard was made. And finally, finding patterns is easy when you assume the patterns are there. (pareidolia or apophenia)

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: and don't forget that forcing a sphere into a rectangle does change the distance between the points on the surface...

Comment: @nico: shhh! :)

Comment: There is no widely-accepted definition for something like a surface center of a sphere, the center of a sphere is not on the surface of it. This question is therefore not answerable.

Comment: @Fabian Instead of closing the question like an inquisitor Fabian. Try to make it more understandable or ask for clarification. English is not my native language I didn't expect anyone to know that but some consideration should be taken in TRYING to understand what is being asked. The FAQ CLEARLY states the following : "If you have a question about the accuracy of public claims made in the media or elsewhere, if you're interested in the evidence behind what you hear or read, then you are in the right place." This is a clear claim made in a video by a recognized media outlet.

Comment: Closing is not final, you can still edit the question and get it reopened. But there is just no sensible way to determine the center on the surface of a sphere that I know of, I wouldn't know how to fix the question.

Comment: If you don't know then ask. I just asked another question on the same subject.

Comment: To everyone else: This question was asked first here, and then re-asked. I have marked THIS as a duplicate, because the other already has an answer, even though it is unconventional.

Comment: To Joze: The goal of closing (not deleting) the question is to get you to edit it into a better question, not to open another question just as bad. Closing the question is just part of the "ask" process, when the problem is serious.

Comment: Closing IS deleting in the practical sense. There is like 1% of questions that get reopened. No one votes to reopen a question it is so rare that it becomes an exception. The problem is even mentioned in meta.